# Setting an inline element's percentage css height, relative to it's flexible parent. (Only problems with chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, inline

## **Problem:**

I'm trying to make a scalable view for images in a lightbox. I've got a way to make it look good on every size of screen. But, only Google Chrome's behavior to this method is different from the other browsers.

### **HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="">
</div>
```

### **CSS:**

I create a helper element, setting it's `display` to `inline-block` and change the `vertical-align` to `middle` for both `span` and `img`. This makes sure the image will be placed in the middle of it's parent.

To make sure the `height` and `width` of the image won't be any bigger than it's parent, I set it both to `90%`. (not `100%` 'cause I want some padding as well).

So my CSS looks like this:

```
.parent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.helper{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
}
```

### **Fiddle**

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0ecmnxo/1/) you can see that it work's in all browsers except for Google Chrome. Chrome ignores the maximum height that's set. Which will allow the image to be bigger than it's parent, not good..

Is there a work-around for this problem?

Comment: Worth to mention, this solution used to be working in Chrome. I didn't change my code on this project, but the outcome did..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out with pure css , no js/jquery. just you need to wrap your content in div and give height 100% to it, as when you say max-height: 80% it takes 80% of it's parent which was not there.

```css
.parent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.helper{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "parentDiv" class="parent">
 <div style="height: 100%;">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img id = "imgId" src="http://3d-diva.davidmichaeldesigns.com/images/tree-01.png"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem! (You've got one too many closing div tag btw)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass height to image tag dynamically with respect to parents div through javascript.

```js
function setImgHt(){
 var imgHeight = document.getElementById('parentDiv').clientHeight;
 document.getElementById('imgId').setAttribute("style","height:"+imgHeight+"px");
}
```

```css
.parent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.helper{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setImgHt()">
<div id = "parentDiv" class="parent">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img id = "imgId" src="http://3d-diva.davidmichaeldesigns.com/images/tree-01.png"/>
</div>
</body>
```

it can be done through jquery as well on document ready call the function which is being called onLoad now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it indeed is a solution. But I'm not too happy with javascript/jQuery solutions when I think it should be possible with pure CSS. I assume you don't have a pure CSS answer, do you?

Comment: let me try out, first thought came to my mind was js/jquery...so did that.

Comment: have posted fresh answer with just css, pls check is it helps.